# DNS Bind9 two IP addresses set up to point to a single server

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm trying to setup my own DNS for a couple of domains that I have. However, I know some domain registrars require two different IPs or two different name servers. I would like to use only one server for this setup.

I know that binds listens on all interfaces by default, so if I have two static IPs, it'll listen to both IPs, is that right?

I'm wondering if it's possible to have this setup and how can I achieve this? Any HOWTOs will be appreciated.

Comment: such...a...bad...idea

Comment: you really should have more than one nameserver. maybe your provider even provides secondary nameservers for you?

Answer (score 6):

Best practice is to have your DNS servers on different physical machines, in different datacenters, run by different people. This maximizes the protection against losing your DNS, but gets expensive.

Some registrars will require that your DNS server IPs not be in the same /24 network, as motivation to do things right.

However, yes, by default bind will listen on all IPs, so it's quite possible to use a setup like you propose.